# Proof for strict inequality $\pi(ab) > \pi(a)\pi(b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

I [asked about](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780183/proving-piab-geq-pia-pib) the very similar $\pi(ab)\geq \pi(a)\pi(b)$ a while ago, and this is indeed a proven result for $a,b\geq \sqrt{53}$.

Empirically, the stricter $\pi(ab)>\pi(a)\pi(b)$ looks true so long as either $a$ or $b$ is $\geq 23$.

It also seems to pretty immediately fall out of the PNT, a la

$$\pi(ab)\sim\frac{ab}{\log(ab)}>\frac{ab}{\log(a)\log(b)}\sim \pi(a)\pi(b)$$

given sufficiently large $a,b$.

---

**If someone can point me to a paper, give pointers/work out on how this proof could be done, or if applicable, explain why this is probably not provable, I'll consider this answered.**

**If you can verify my proof below or give some solid feedback, that would work too.**

---

Okay, I have a first attempt. For $x\geq 17$, Wikipedia gives the bounds

$$\frac x {\log x} < \pi(x) \tag{1}$$

$$\pi(x) < 1.25506 \frac x {\log x}. \tag{2}$$

From applying $(2)$ twice, we have

$$\pi(a)\pi(b) < 1.25506^2 \cdot  \frac{ab}{\log(a)\log(b)}.\tag{3}$$

From $(1)$, we get $$\frac{ab}{\log(ab)} < \pi(ab).\tag{4}$$

It only remains to connect them:

$$1.25506^2 \cdot  \frac{ab}{\log(a)\log(b)} < \frac{ab}{\log(ab)}.\tag{5}$$

From trial and error, letting $a,b \geq 24$ seems sufficient to satisfy $(5)$. We put the pieces together and get the final inequality chain

$$\pi(a)\pi(b) < 1.25506^2 \cdot  \frac{ab}{\log(a)\log(b)} <\frac{ab}{\log(ab)} < \pi(ab). \tag{6}$$

This gives $\pi(a)\pi(b)<\pi(ab)$ for $a,b\geq 24$. Have I gone awry somewhere or does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish the proof , we only have to show $(5)$ for $a,b\ge 24$

WLOG we can assume $24\le a\le b$ and therefore $\ln(a)\le \ln(b)$.

Then we have $$\frac{\ln(a)\cdot \ln(b)}{\ln(ab)}=\frac{\ln(a)\cdot \ln(b)}{\ln(a)+\ln(b)}\ge \frac{\ln(24)\cdot \ln(b)}{2\ln(b)}=\frac{\ln(24)}{2}>1.25506^2$$ hence $$\frac{\ln(a)\cdot \ln(b)}{\ln(ab)}>1.25506^2$$

which is equivalent to $(5)$ finishing the proof.